# Unable to get class of parent form inside jquery validation plugin custom method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to add a custom method with jquery validation plugin and inside call the class of form.
This is my code

```
$.validator.addMethod("compareDates", function (value, element) {
            var el = element.closest("form");
            var class = el.attr('class');
}, "Message");

  $(".myform").validate({
        rules: {
            date_to: {
                required: true,
                compareDates: true
            }
        }
    });
```

But instead of getting class of form I get this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: el.attr is not a function.  Exception occurred
>   when checking element date_to, check the 'compareDates' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like I need to add $(element). So the code should be,

```
var el = $(element).closest("form");
```

I'm keeping this in case anyone else came up with same error.